# Shorter syntax of conditional or against many Strings

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have something like this:

```
if(this.selectedItem.label == "str1"
   || this.selectedItem.label == "str2"
   || this.selectedItem.label == "str3"
   || this.selectedItem.label == "str4") {
}
```

I wonder if exist shorter syntax to use "this.selectedItem.label" only one.

Comment: this kind of question is better asked at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

May be array and [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) function ?

```
if(["str1","str2","str3","str4"].indexOf(this.selectedItem.label) > -1){
  // found
}
```

That's a cross browser solution.

Oh well, [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) (*haven't tested* in IE)

```
if(["str1","str2","str3","str4"].includes(this.selectedItem.label)){

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(["str1", "str2"].indexOf(this.selectedItem.label) !== -1) {
   // TO DO 
}
```