# Better way to do this if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am trying to improve some of my JS skills.

I have a number of colours in hex which are in an object stored as foreground colours and background colours.

When the width of the webpage is a particular size i want to make sure that some specific colours are NOT used from the object to change the text colour.

How heres what I have so far. This works fine...and i know i could use a switch too but can anyone else improve the if || statemenent please?

```
 var colorThemes = [
        // Combo 1:
        { foreground: "#0A1C6B", background: "#5DF0AD" },
        // Combo 2:
        { foreground: "#C2F5FF", background: "#0A1C6B" },
        // Combo 3:
        { foreground: "#583985", background: "#CCCCF0" },
        // Combo 4:
        { foreground: "#FBBEA6", background: "#5839B5" },
        // Combo 5:
        { foreground: "#8A350D", background: "#FFDB0D" }
    ]

   var randomnumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * colorThemes.length));

   var selector = colorThemes[randomnumber]

   if (selector.foreground === "#0A1C6B" || selector.foreground === "#5DF0AD" || selector.foreground === "#C2F5FF" || selector.foreground === "#ABD1fA" || selector.foreground === "#FBBEA6" || selector.foreground === "#FACCD4" || selector.foreground === "#FF5919" ||  selector.foreground === "#D9F2AD" || selector.foreground === "#83BF25"){

            copyCount[i].style.color = selector.background;

            }
        }'
```

Thank you

Comment: What's the reason for such an if statement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: Answered similar  question few hours back https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45711665/shorter-syntax-of-conditional-or-against-many-strings

Comment: Hi - you probably want to check if an item is in an array.  Look here for a quick review: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try with `Array#filter`

```
if (colorThemes.filter(a => (selector.foreground === a.foreground|| selector.foreground == a.background)).length > 0) {
  copyCount[i].style.color = selector.background;
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array including all the colors and then check that the selected color is included in this array.

```js
const colorThemes = [
  { foreground: "#0A1C6B", background: "#5DF0AD" },
  { foreground: "#C2F5FF", background: "#0A1C6B" },
  { foreground: "#583985", background: "#CCCCF0" },
  { foreground: "#FBBEA6", background: "#5839B5" },
  { foreground: "#8A350D", background: "#FFDB0D" }
]

const colors = colorThemes.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc.push(curr.foreground, curr.background);
  
  return acc;
}, []);

const randomnumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * colorThemes.length));

const selector = colorThemes[randomnumber]

if (colors.includes(selector.foreground)) {
  console.log('Success');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) with an array for the colors.

```js
var colorThemes = [{ foreground: "#0A1C6B", background: "#5DF0AD" }, { foreground: "#C2F5FF", background: "#0A1C6B" }, { foreground: "#583985", background: "#CCCCF0" }, { foreground: "#FBBEA6", background: "#5839B5" }, { foreground: "#8A350D", background: "#FFDB0D" }],
    randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * colorThemes.length),
    selector = colorThemes[randomnumber],
    changeColors = ["#0A1C6B", "#5DF0AD", "#C2F5FF", "#ABD1fA", "#FBBEA6", "#FACCD4", "#FF5919", "#D9F2AD", "#83BF25"];

if (changeColors.indexOf(selector.foreground) !== -1) {
    console.log('change color!');
    //copyCount[i].style.color = selector.background;
}
```

With ES6 you could use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for the colors

```js
var colorThemes = [{ foreground: "#0A1C6B", background: "#5DF0AD" }, { foreground: "#C2F5FF", background: "#0A1C6B" }, { foreground: "#583985", background: "#CCCCF0" }, { foreground: "#FBBEA6", background: "#5839B5" }, { foreground: "#8A350D", background: "#FFDB0D" }],
    randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * colorThemes.length),
    selector = colorThemes[randomnumber],
    colorSet = new Set(["#0A1C6B", "#5DF0AD", "#C2F5FF", "#ABD1fA", "#FBBEA6", "#FACCD4", "#FF5919", "#D9F2AD", "#83BF25"]);

if (colorSet.has(selector.foreground)) {
    console.log('change color!');
    //copyCount[i].style.color = selector.background;
} else {
    console.log('nothing has changed!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an if statement.  They are code-smells.

```
var colorThemes = {
  "#0A1C6B": "#5DF0AD"
  , "#C2F5FF": "#0A1C6B"
  , "#583985": "#CCCCF0"
  , "#FBBEA6": "#5839B5"
  , "#8A350D": "#FFDB0D"
};

var foregroundColors = Object.keys(colorThemes);
var randomForegroundIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * colorThemes.length);
var randomForeground = foregroundColors[randomForegroundIdx];
copyCount[i].style.color = colorThemes[randomForeground];
```